# Dictionary works for len(string) multiple of 3. Function deletes remainders but now doesn't translate with dictionary. Python 2.7.1

Tags: python, string, function, split

I made a function with a dictionary.  The purpose of the function is to separate the input string into sets of 3 . If the input string value is not a multiple of 3, I want to delete the remainder [1 or 2]

my function was working perfectly until I added the part for deleting the remainders

```
def func(fx):
    d={'AAA':1,'BBB':2,'CCC':3}
    length=len(fx)
    if length % 3 == 0:
        return fx
    if length % 3 == 1:
        return fx[:-1]
    if length % 3 == 2:
        return fx[:-2]
    Fx=fx.upper()
    Fx3=[Fx[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(Fx),3)]
    translate=[d[x] for x in Fx3]
    return translate


x='aaabbbcc'

output = func(x)

print output

>>>
aaabbb
```

---

the function is recognizing that the input sequence is not a multiple of 3 so its deleting the 2 values which is what i want.  However, its splitting the new string into 3 letter words to be translated with my dictionary anymore.  If you delete the if statements, the function works but only for strings that are a multiple of 3.

What am I doing wrong ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning fx when you probably should be reassigning it

```
def func(fx):
    d={'AAA':1,'BBB':2,'CCC':3}
    length=len(fx)
    if length % 3 == 0:
        pass
    elif length % 3 == 1:
        fx = fx[:-1]
    elif length % 3 == 2:
        fx = fx[:-2]
    Fx=fx.upper()
    Fx3=[Fx[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(Fx),3)]
    translate=[d[x] for x in Fx3]
    return translate
```

Here is an alternate function for you to figure out when you know some more Python

```
def func(fx):
    d = {'AAA':1,'BBB':2,'CCC':3}
    return [d["".join(x).upper()] for x in zip(*[iter(fx)]*3)]
```

Comment: awesome thank you.  I'm confused tho . . . I thought the if statement is a function within a function which requires a return?

Comment: @draconist, no, `if` is just a control structure. It would be a syntax error to return there if it wasn't inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
def func(fx):
    d = {'AAA': 1, 'BBB': 2, 'CCC': 3}

    fx = fx[:-(len(fx)%3)].upper()

    groups = [fx[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(fx), 3)]

    translate = [d[group] for group in groups]

    return translate

x='aaabbbcc'

print func(x)
```

When trimming the end of the string, you were returning the result when you wanted to just store it in a variable or assign it back to fx.

Rather than the `if .. elif`s you can just use the result of the length modulo 3 directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of a function, it can be done in a one liner less complex than the gnibbler's one.
Acom's solution is nearly mine.

```
d={'AAA':1,'BBB':2,'CCC':3}

for fx in ('bbbcccaaabbbcccbbbcccaaabbbcc',
           'bbbcccaaabbbaaa','bbbcccaaabbbaa','bbbcccaaabbba',
           'bbbcccaaabbb','bbbcccaaabb','bbbcccaaab',
           'bbbcccaaa','bbbcccaa','bbbccca',
           'bbbccc','bbbcc','bbbc',
           'bbb','bb','b',''):
    print fx
    print tuple( d[fx[i:i+3].upper()] for i in xrange(0, len(fx)-len(fx)%3, 3) )
```

produces

```
bbbcccaaabbbcccbbbcccaaabbbcc
(2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2)
bbbcccaaabbbaaa
(2, 3, 1, 2, 1)
bbbcccaaabbbaa
(2, 3, 1, 2)
bbbcccaaabbba
(2, 3, 1, 2)
bbbcccaaabbb
(2, 3, 1, 2)
bbbcccaaabb
(2, 3, 1)
bbbcccaaab
(2, 3, 1)
bbbcccaaa
(2, 3, 1)
bbbcccaa
(2, 3)
bbbccca
(2, 3)
bbbccc
(2, 3)
bbbcc
(2,)
bbbc
(2,)
bbb
(2,)
bb
()
b
()

()
```

.

I think you have to treat strings that can contain only 3 characters strings 'aaa','bbb','ccc' at the positions 0,3,6,9,etc
Then the preceding programs won't crash if there's an heterogenous 3-characters string at one of these positions instead of one of these set 'aaa','bbb','ccc'

In this case, note that you could use the dictionary's method **get** that returns a default value when a pased argument isn't a key of the dictionary.

In the following code, I put the default returned value as 0:

```
d={'AAA':1,'BBB':2,'CCC':3}

for fx in ('bbbcccaaa###bbbccc"""bbbcc',
           'bbb   aaabbbaaa','bbbccc^^^bbbaa','bbbc;;;aabbba',
           'bbbc^caaabbb',']]bccca..bb','bbb%%%aaab',
           'bbbcccaaa','bbb!ccaa','b@bccca',
           'bbbccc','bbbcc','bbbc',
           'b&b','bb','b',''):
    print fx
    print [d.get(fx[i:i+3].upper(), 0) for i in xrange(0, len(fx)-len(fx)%3, 3)]
```

produces

```
bbbcccaaa###bbbccc"""bbbcc
[2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2]
bbb   aaabbbaaa
[2, 0, 1, 2, 1]
bbbccc^^^bbbaa
[2, 3, 0, 2]
bbbc;;;aabbba
[2, 0, 0, 2]
bbbc^caaabbb
[2, 0, 1, 2]
]]bccca..bb
[0, 3, 0]
bbb%%%aaab
[2, 0, 1]
bbbcccaaa
[2, 3, 1]
bbb!ccaa
[2, 0]
b@bccca
[0, 3]
bbbccc
[2, 3]
bbbcc
[2]
bbbc
[2]
b&b
[0]
bb
[]
b
[]

[]
```

By the way, I preferred to create a tuple instead of a list because for the kind of invariable objects that are in the result, I think it is better not to create a list